# How to attach file to main workflow item via infopath task form

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, designer-workflow, attachments

While approving the task, Approver(Vice President) wants ability to delete existing attachment and attach the new file to main workflow item.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?  Any help will be appreciated.